# LM358n versus LM386 for audio amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, lm386

Here's the pinout diagram for an LM358

[image: lm358 dual op-amp]

Here's the pinout diagram for the LM386:

[image: lm386 op-amp]

Here's a very basic circuit showing an audio amplifier created using an LM386:

[image: audio amplifier via lm386]

- If I built the equivalent circuit using the LM358, would it work in a similar way?  Or would it fail since the chip has no gain?
  (I've built the equivalent circuit and it did not seem to work.  Didn't know if I was doing something else incorrectly though.)
- Is there a way to compensate for the lack of gain in the LM358?
- Is it possible to create a very simple audio amplifier using an LM358 or is it basically not feasible due to its characteristics / abilities?

Comment: what do you mean has no gain? the LM358 has enormous gain, that's the entire point of an op amp.

Comment: They're not interchangeable. LM386 is an audio amp, intended to drive a speaker. It's not any kind of opamp like the LM358 is.

Comment: Never use the LM358 for audio. Even for intermediate stages. Too many better choices, so find something better. And as others have mentioned the LM386 is a power amplifier and never used for similar applications as the LM358. Different horses for different courses, entirely. You can see some of the LM380 (similar to the LM386) [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rKfep.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add feedback resistors to obtain a reasonable gain. But, your problem is that the LM358 isn't designed to drive a speaker.

Answer (score 3):

They're two completely different parts, even though they share a schematic symbol.

The LM358 is a dual op amp, the LM386 is a power amplifier with default gain set and designed to drive a small speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried to see if I could get the lm358n to work as an audio amp but had no luck so I would just go for the lm386

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but it's not clear what the point of your post is. Luck isn't going to make an op-amp work as a power amplifier. The explanation has been given several times in the other answers.